# firefox (9), javascript, allocation size overflow due to big data file. Is there any way to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, firefox, size, overflow, allocation

I am working on a web app that amongst other things, does a first conversion reading a .csv file and converting to a .xml file.

I have a file of 20 mb, which is well processed (so the code is ok).

But I have a file of 80 mb, and the process stops with the message in the Error Console

Error: allocation size overflow

And it points to the last line of an object that stores a large xml string.

The code basically splits the .csv file, for each line splits again the line, and then re-builds the content with xml tags which are added to the variable.

Then I assume that with 80 mb (.csv file) the size of the string is just too big for Firefox.

My question is, is there anything that I can do about it, like splitting the variable or similar workarounds? Or this would be a loss of time?

Thanks

Comment: Are you freeing the memory ? like delete or setting the unusefull vars to null?

Comment: I am not. I though JS makes automatic garbage collection. Is there any way to see what is the memory being used by JS within the execution of the script? To do like an automatic checking of a value, either to give a nice message before this error occurs, or to troubleshoot whether any solution (as freeing memory) is working?

Comment: firebug could tell you the memoryProfile and could point you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you! I did not know this extension. Installing it right now :)

Answer (score 0):

this question looks very old but I have found some solution for this. You can use the URL API's for modern browsers.

```
var file = document.getElementById('video').files[0];
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var video = document.querySelector("#vid");
video.preload = 'metadata';
video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
   window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
   let time = video.duration;
   console.log(video.duration);
}
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```